# unable to typecast in pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am getting errors in AVG function. Can anyone please help on the following script: (Do i need to use tuple or bag while loading?) Thanks.

```
mydata = LOAD 'bigdata.txt' USING PigStorage(',')  AS (stn , wban, yearmoda,   temp, a ,  dewp :double, b ,  slp :double,  c,  stp :double, d, visib :double, e,  wdsp :double,  f, mxspd :double,  gust :double,   max :double,  min :double, prcp :double, sndp :double, frshtt);

clean1 = FOREACH mydata GENERATE stn , wban, yearmoda,   temp, a ,  dewp, b ,  slp,  c,  stp, d, visib, e,  wdsp,  f, mxspd,  gust,   max ,  min, prcp  ,sndp , frshtt;

--clean2 = FILTER clean1 BY (temp == 9999.9);

tmpdata = FOREACH clean1 GENERATE stn, SUBSTRING(yearmoda, 0, 5) as year, temp;
C = GROUP tmpdata BY (year, temp);

avgtemp = FOREACH C GENERATE group, AVG(temp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not assign `temp` a type when you `LOAD`ed your data.  So when Pig tries to call the `AVG` function, and it checks to see which version of it to use (since it must behave differently if the field is an `int` rather than a `double`, for example), it cannot tell how to proceed.  Give `temp` a type (like `temp:int`) in your `LOAD` statement and it should work.

In your case, you have also not specified the field correctly.  You need to pass `AVG` a bag to evaluate.  You construct this bag by projecting the `temp` field out of the bag of records in `C`.  The schema of `C` is `{(group:(year,temp)), tmpdata:{(stn,year:chararray,temp)})}`, so you need to compute `avgtemp` like this:

```
avgtemp = FOREACH C GENERATE group, AVG(tmpdata.temp);
```

Comment: it says:
 Projected field [temp] does not exist in schema: group:tuple(year:chararray,temp:double),tmpdata:bag{:tuple(stn:bytearray,year:chararray,temp:double)}.

Comment: Thankyou so much. it worked. but my data is not readable. (I am printing using dump right now. its a 35MB file. is that ok?) 

Also, can you refer a command for filtering values like 9999 from a column... Thanks.

Comment: Try to figure out what you can, and then post another question detailing what you have tried and the specific errors you are running into.

Comment: for the previous problem..I get some data (360Kb) as output but its not readable. (part-r-00000 file) does it mean my program is incorrect.